# Basic difference between fixed and fluid row in twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Can any one tell me what is the difference between fixed and fluid row in twitter bootstrap. I am a beginner.

Thanks,
Abhi

Answer (score 23):

Fixed rows are a given pixel width (940px) split between 12 columns.

Fluid rows are percentages based (100%) again split between 12 columns.

This information is readily available **[here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem)**